# how do you insert into oracle table with php

Tags: php, oracle

I am trying to insert into an oracle table via a php script.

My sample data is this:

```
$sql="insert into VMSTAT_PRD (DATE, LPAR, lcpu, mem, ent, r, b, p, avm, free, fi, fo, pi, po, fr, sr, in_faults, sy, cs, usr, sys, idle, waitio, pc, ec) VALUES ('2013-06-27 14:52:54','servera',96,393216,16.00,8,1,0,50104312,279318,5291,632,0,0,5799,10185,4533,74621,32708,5,4,91,1,1.87,11.7)";

$conn=odbc_connect('Odbc_name','user','passwd');
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
```

I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
, SQL state S1000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\PHP\cpu.php on line 100

Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
, SQL state S1000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\PHP\cpu.php on line 100
Error in SQL
```

Any ideas what this error message mean?

Comment: You are missing some code. Show what $sql line you have.

Comment: sql line is in here. starts with insert into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use preparing to insert into the database really.

```
   $conn=odbc_connect('Odbc_name','user','passwd');


   $sql="insert into VMSTAT_PRD (DATE, LPAR, lcpu, mem, ent, r, b, p, avm, free, fi, fo, pi, po, fr, sr, in_faults, sy, cs, usr, sys, idle, waitio, pc, ec) VALUES ('2013-06-27 14:52:54','cigp01a2a001',96,393216,16.00,8,1,0,50104312,279318,5291,632,0,0,5799,10185,4533,74621,32708,5,4,91,1,1.87,11.7)";
   $prepare = odbc_prepare($conn, $sql);
   $rs=odbc_execute($prepare);
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error (ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword). Should I convert the date to oracle dat before attempting to insert?

Comment: this is the error: "Warning: odbc_execute(): SQL error: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
, SQL state S1000 in SQLExecute in C:\PHP\cpu.php on line 101
Error in SQL"